# cURL returns 404 while the page is found in browser

Tags: php, curl

there is already similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of their solutions have been working for me.  I'm trying to grab a page on LoveIt.com with cURL, but it returns me a 404 error, while the url works fine in the browser :

```
        $url = 'http://loveit.com/loves/P0D1jlFaIOzzZfZqj_bY3KV';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://loveit.com/');
```

Here's the header I receive :

> Array ( [url] => http://loveit.com/loves/P0D1jlFaIOzzZfZqj_bY3KV [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 404 [header_size] => 667 [request_size] => 172 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.320466 [namelookup_time] => 0.000326 [connect_time] => 0.119046 [pretransfer_time] => 0.119089 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 499 [speed_download] => 1557 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 499 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.320438 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => --- [primary_port] => 80 [local_ip] => --- [local_port] => 53837 [redirect_url] => )

I read that some website had protections against this kind of scripts; and I did test some solutions proposed, but none worked for me (CURLOPT_USERAGENT,CURLOPT_REFERER...)

Any ideas of what's happening here ?

I would like to backup my LoveIt account, that's why i'm making this (no exports functions and no replies from LoveIt.com about the health of the website)

Comment: are you recreating the browser environment EXACTLY? e.g. getting curl to send any cookies the browser might be? referer checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly checked the said page with LiveHeaders enabled and I noticed bunch of cookies set. I suspect that, since it's not "normal" url, you need to hand those cookies while being redirected otherwise you end being kicked out with 404. Use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` with your cURL instance at start. See: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue with a site. In my case they were expecting a USER_AGENT to be set so anyone with this issue in the future should also check that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save the cookie file via chrome.

You can create a function to get this cookie, and then reuse it.

Like:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Class Crawler{

   var $cookie;
   var $http_response;
   var $user_agent;

   function __construct($cookie){
       $this->cookie     = (string) $cookie;
       $this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0'; 
   }

   function get($url){
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
       // Here we create the file with cookies
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
       $this->http_response = curl_exec($ch);
   }

   function get_with_cookies($url){
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);

       // Here we can re-use the cookie file keeping the save of the cookies 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
       $this->http_response = curl_exec($ch);
    }
}

$crawler = new Crawler('cookie_file_name');
// Creating cookie file
$crawler->get('uri');
// Request with the cookies
$crawler->get_with_cookies('uri');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, so I did visit the page, saved the cookies in a cookies.txt file (with chrome extenson cookie.txt export) that I use NOT CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, but for option **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**.

```
$cookiefile = './cookie.txt';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
```

and now it works !  Thanks for your feedback, it was really useful.