# cuRL returnin 404 error

Tags: php, http, curl

I`m using cuRL to get some data from remote server... The response is in JSON format..
This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.myaddress.com/mypage.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("id" => $id));
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If I access the link in the browser the page load OK, but if I access through the cuRL return a 404 error...

Comment: Can you check first the header of the page called, to verify if you have code 200 or something else?

Comment: Also, did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476828/curl-returns-404-while-the-page-is-found-in-browser

Comment: The curl_getinfo returns 404 in the http_code

Comment: For the same url, what http status do you get [here](http://web-sniffer.net/)?

Comment: Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: @giordanolima did you check my answer with the link inside?

Comment: Yes, but nothing. Because my link don`t manage cookies... It`s just a JSON answer...

Comment: If there's a 200 from the test, possibly no cookies issue, try to simulate a browser better, by using custom headers: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $custom_headers);`

Comment: I tried custom headers and keep the problem...

Comment: If you got 200 from the other site, try with similar request headers.

Comment: I don`t know if the server that i am sending the post data have give permission for remote posts...

Comment: Just because it's only JSON in the response doesn't mean cookies aren't being exchanged. Did you wireshark/Fiddler the requests/responses from the browser?

Comment: Look at my answer below for an explanation of what you need to do. [Here](http://pastebin.com/hverfZX6) also is an example I pulled from my junk-php directory which is similar and should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Is the URL accessible? If so, can you share it here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can guess a few things that it can be checked from the server side, to show the error.

**1)** As it is stated in other answers, be sure to set all the necessary headers, you can check them e.g. by firebug, as it is shown in here,

[image]

or you can get the headers by php [get_headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.
to set it use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HeaderName: HeaderValue"));
```

**2)** When you open a page in the browser(excluding form submit with post method) it makes a get request, instead of post, so if in the server side it is checked $_GET, then your post request will not be considered.

**3)** If you sure that it should be a post request(say, it is a form submit), then the following can be a problem: some forms can have hidden fields, that again are being checked in the server, and if they are not set, error can be returned. So, you should look at the source code of the form and add them(if there are any) to your post parameters.

**4)** if you are submitting a form, be sure to set the submit button with its name and value as well, because similar to hidden fields, this can be checked as well.

**5)** Cookies can be a problem as well, because by default browser has it , and curl does not. To to able to set and read cookies use this code

```
// set cookie 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    
// use cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

here, `$cookie_file` path to the cookies file. Do not know in linux or mac, but in windows be sure to use absolute path to the cookie file.

**6)** Also, you can set the referer by

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.myaddress.com/mypage.php');
```

**EDIT:** In case of ajax request you might want to add a header `X-Requested-With` with value as `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 5):

It's possible the server check the HTTP Header, it's the case in the majority of case.

So add the same HTTP Header of your browser, verify with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/network) :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('SomeName: SomeValue'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is something else the browser is sending your cURL code is not. You can use any of the tools other folks have suggested, Firebug, Wireshark, Fiddler, etc, etc.

What you need to do is add missing pieces to your request to match the browser as closely as possible in the cURL request until the remote page responds with a 200.

I notice you're doing a `POST`. In many cases what happens with your browser is you visit a page with a `GET` request. A session is initialized on the remote site and a cookie is saved in your browser with the session id.

This cookie then needs to be supplied along with subsequent `POST` requests. [PHP cURL](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt) has many options to support cookies. There may be other requirements such as [CSRF tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and so forth.

Again, reverse-engineering is the key.

Comment: Agree. Debug it using Fiddler or Burp Suite, then send the same data.