# Curl not redirecting to page

Tags: php, curl

When I use the following code, i redirects to my own domain with https (I get 404 error because I dont use SSL on my domain)

EDIT: If my URL where the curl script is http://example.com/index.php it redirecting to http**s**://example.com.com/index.php

It's not the same problem as other questions.
I get error 404. I dont get the error with where I need to use      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

```
$url = 'https://www.homepage.com';
$fields = array('username'=>'abc', 'password'=>'1234', 'loginbutton'=> 'Login');

$postvars='';
$sep='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{
    $postvars.= $sep.urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
    $sep='&';
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: This may help [cuRL returnin 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001264/curl-returnin-404-error)

Comment: could somebody please help?

Comment: Hi Hans, Welcome to SO.  I see you've edited your question but it's still a bit unclear what is going on.  Can you include the output of `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); var_dump(curl_error($ch));` after the call to `curl_exec()`?  It sounds like the 404 issue may be a server configuration (.htaccess?) problem rather than a curl problem.