# curl ip returned 404, but type ip into chrome, everything works well,why?

Tags: linux, curl

## Description:

I resolve the `ip` of `www.baidu.com`, which is `103.235.46.39`. Then I **curl** it `curl 103.235.46.39`, **curl** returned `HTTP 404`. And then I type the ip address to chrome browser, everything goes well.

## Question:

**What happend to Curl? Did I omit some Curl option?**

Comment: This question has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476828/curl-returns-404-while-the-page-is-found-in-browser?rq=1) a [few times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001264/curl-returnin-404-error?noredirect=1&lq=1).  It most likely has to do with you not replicating the various headers and cookies required.

Comment: @Jason That's right, thank you. ^_^