# php curl post long string gives 404

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying for almost a week to send a long string value with php curl post with no success till I tried `Expect:` to avoid `Expect:100-continue`.

send_request.php script:

```
$array = array(
    'value' => $short_string, # less than 1024 characters
    'long_value' => $long_string, # more than 1024 characters (1400000 in my case)
);
$array = http_build_query($array);
$headers = array('Expect:');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain_name.com/url/to/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

process_request.php script:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $response = 'okay short string';
    if(isset($_POST['long_value'])){
        $response = 'okay long string';
    }
    echo $response;
}
```

Now my code doesn't exceed time limit but gives me the following:

[this happens when sending short and long string or just long]

`curl_error($ch)` prints `SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno= 0`
and `curl_exec($ch)` retrieves the code for the **404 not found page from the url set for the curl post request**.

[this happens when sending short string]

`curl_error($ch)` is `null`
and `curl_exec($ch)` retrieves `'okay short string'`

**Does anyone know how to solve this cause I'm starting to believe it's impossible...(?)**

**NOTE:** $long_string is a select query from my local database encoded with `json_encode` and then encrypted with `AES-256-CBC` in case this helps on finding a solution...

**UPDATE [SOLUTION]:**

I just removed the `$array = http_build_query($array)` line and send data as `json_encode` without encrypt and it works. Takes almost 4 minutes to get response but at least it works.

Comment: It's not the same cause my issue is based only on the length of the string I pass as `$_POST`. If I send the short one it works fine but retrieves 404 if sending the long one... @cale_b

Comment: So - in your question, address that head on - and indicate the things you've tried (based on the answers in the other question).  Otherwise, how would anyone know what you have / haven't tried? For example, you ARE NOT setting your header, and one of the recommendations in the answers was to be sure your headers are set properly....

Comment: Check the setting of your `post_max_size` in `php.ini`.

Comment: I just found a solution. Thanks anyway @AlexHowansky!

Answer (score 0):

try to To increase PHP execution timeout, increase in php.ini. To see where your php.ini is located, see phpinfo().

```
max_execution_time = 60 #this is in seconds
```

if you are on nginx: 
To increase nginx's timeout on reading from backend, increase in nginx config (nginx/nginx.conf).

```
proxy_read_timeout 60
```

[More](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout)

cURL
This is an assumption, but since you say you are making a POST request, increase cURL timeout

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

[More](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: PHP execution time is increased to 300 (5 minutes) and if you read my code you'll see that cURL timeout is already increased...

Comment: can you check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001264/curl-returnin-404-error

Comment: checked but the point is why is giving me error 404 **ONLY** when I post the `$long_string`? and how can I fix this?

Comment: probably im assuming that it comes from th URL/API try to use Postman to post "long_value" and see if the page will return 404, if yes then the problem is not from CURL

Comment: I just found a solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: perfect! can you post in an answer what was the solution you found ?

Comment: i posted it on the question itself! hope it could help anyone who find the same issue or similar :)