# curl post not working to send json data using REST API developed in java

Tags: java, php, rest, api, curl

I am trying to send json data from my php file using a REST API which is developed in java to store data into database.
This is my code.

```
$p_name = $_POST['p_name'];
    $tick = $_POST['tick'];


    $url3 = 'http://myipaddress:port/myurl/';
    $cookie_file =dirname(__FILE__).'\cookiefile.txt';

    $form_data = array(
        'p_name' => $p_name,
        'tick' => $tick
    );
    $str = json_encode($form_data);
    $ch = curl_init($url3);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($str)
    ) );
    // set cookie
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    // use cookie
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
        $response3 = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    $responseHTTP = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result3 = json_decode($response3);

    var_dump($responseHTTP);
```

This is the code of java section.

```
@POST
@Path("/mypath")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String savePortFolioRecords(MyObject list_myobject){
    String return_string=null;
    try{
        mydataManager dataManager=new mydataManager();
        dataManager.setup();
        dataManager.insertRecordsApi(list_myobject);
        dataManager.exit();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        return_string=gson.toJson("successfully insert the data");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Giving Exception due to: "+e);
    }
    return return_string;
}
```

While i am testing the API using postman, it works perfectly and insert data into database, but in response box shows a text like **`Unexpected 's'`** .
But while i am trying to send value from my php file using curl, it does not store data into database. I don't understand whether my function in php 
does not send data or can't receive json data in java section.

Moreover, when i am using `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` and print the corresponding response using `var_dump`, it shows `int(404)`.
I have followed these links to solve my problem, but can't get any solution.

> [cuRL returnin 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001264/curl-returnin-404-error/21863524)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476828/curl-returns-404-while-the-page-is-found-in-browser](http://cURL%20returns%20404%20while%20the%20page%20is%20found%20in%20browser)

https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Can any one tell me what's the problem here? I can't understand whether it is problem in my php file or in the java file.

Comment: /myurl/ != /myurl

Comment: I am just trying to give you an insight about my approach. Though I already edited  for your convenience. I hope you would understand now.