# Get RSS via cURL, fine in browser but 404 error in terminal

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, curl, rss

A client want that we deliver content via RSS feed, they use cURL to get the feed contents, but they say that they get an 404 error instead. I have tried this command in the terminal: `$ curl -g --compressed http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php > temp.xml` and as the client says I get the 404 page instead of the feed. When I type the URI in the browser it shows the feed without problem.

I cannot change anything in the client app, so, how can I ensure that they get the feed instead of the 404 error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `curl` returns a 404 status page:

```
$ curl -g --compressed http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php -s -o /dev/null -D-
HTTP/1.1 **404 Not Found**
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 08:12:27 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://mediosymedia.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Many webservers will be suspicious of requests without a browser `User-Agent` because they expect `curl` to be used for scraping. This is probably not the smartest technique because a simple UserAgent spoofing will fix that problem:

```
$ curl -g --compressed http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php -s -o /dev/null -D- -H'User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'
HTTP/1.1 **200 OK**
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 08:13:46 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

So, in practice, make sure you set up a User-Agent for your requests that is not Curl's.

Comment: +1 - this is the correct answer. I've tested it and confirmed that a useragent is required.

Comment: Thank you @JulienGenestoux, with your fix works in terminal. But, how can I set up the user agent? As I said I cannot modify —or ask a modification— of the client app, so I will need to do it on my end.

Comment: I have talked with my hosting company and they added a mod_security exception for that feed, so it works now without the user agent. Thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 0):

My initial though was that this may be related to cookies (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476828/curl-returns-404-while-the-page-is-found-in-browser)), but this may be a localized issue. This is working fine from my machine:

```
[root@devtest tmp]# curl -g --compressed http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plug
ins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php > temp.xml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27926    0 27926    0     0  54564      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 69815
```

### CORRECTION:

Thanks to Julien for pointing out that the contents of the downloaded file was the custom 404 page contents. As he mentions, you need to add a useragent flag (`-A`) to your `curl` requests:

```
# curl -A "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1
; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"-g --compressed http://medio
symedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php > temp.xml
```

I would just delete my answer, but it's worth leaving up as a warning to others who might be experiencing this issue - make sure you validate the response!

Comment: I also had no problems in retrieving it as well.

Comment: Well, I get the same output, but that's indeed a 404!

Comment: @JulienGenestoux - good catch! I'm not sure why, but I was expecting that a returned 404 header would trigger some flag on the response. I should have looked at the actual return value.